# Show large picture from thumbnails in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 thumbnails to the left, and when I click on one of them I waht to show a large picture to the right on the screen.

My problem is, that for some reason it shows 8 small thumbnails (first 4 and then 4 again). The first four ones are not clickable. The last four ones are clickable and correctly shows the larger image.

So, where does the first four thumbnails come from, and how do I get rid of them?

I have a transparant image (Picture.gif) that is the larger picture that is changed and shows the bigger versions of the thumbnails.

My html:

```
<body onLoad="init()">

      <table class="planes">

      <tr>
       <td>
         <ul>              
         <div id="thumb">
           <li><img src="img/Plane1.jpg" alt="Plane1"></li>
           <li><img src="img/Plane2.jpg" alt="Plane2"></li>
           <li><img src="img/Plane3.jpg" alt="Plane3"></li>
           <li><img src="img/Plane4.jpg" alt="Plane4"></li>
         </div>
         </ul>
       </td>
       <td>                      
         <img class="pic" id="main" src="img/Picture.gif" alt="">
       </td>   
      </tr>
   </table>
```

My javascript:

```
var images= new Array('img/Plane1.jpg', 'img/Plane2.jpg', 'img/Plane3.jpg', 'img/Plane4.jpg');
var imgList = new Array();

function init() 
{
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) 
    {
        imgList[i] = new Image();
        imgList[i].src = images[i];
        document.getElementById('thumb').appendChild(imgList[i]);
        imgList[i].addEventListener("click", swap, false)
    }
}


function swap(evtObj) 
{
    var imgfile = evtObj.target.getAttribute('src');
    var mainTag = document.getElementById('main');
    mainTag.src = imgfile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 4 images are the ones you have in your static html code. The next 4 are the dynamic generated from javascrip. Just remove the images inside thumb from your html code.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
document.getElementById('thumb').appendChild(imgList[i]);
```

You are appending the image to the 'thumb' list again. But these are the ones you want to keep, as they have the eventListener attached to them.

You need to remove the  tags from your html code to achieve the desired result.

```
<li><img src="img/Plane1.jpg" alt="Plane1"></li>
<li><img src="img/Plane2.jpg" alt="Plane2"></li>
<li><img src="img/Plane3.jpg" alt="Plane3"></li>
<li><img src="img/Plane4.jpg" alt="Plane4"></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is exactly what the problem was

Comment: One more question: How can I align the four thumbnails under each other now when I don't have the list? (I had css that put the images under each other vertically).

Comment: You could delete the `div` with the id `thumb` and put that id on the `ul` element. Afterwards, create an `li` element using `document.createElement('li')` and append the image to it, then append the `li` to the `ul` element.

Answer (score 1):

The images are both in your html, and also created in javascript.

The line `document.getElementById('thumb').appendChild(imgList[i]);` adds each image specified in the images array of your javascript to the page.

I suggest you will want to remove the ones in your html - simply remove the `<li>` tags and the images that are within them.

After taking out the unneeded tags, your HTML should look something like this:

```
<body onLoad="init()">

      <table class="planes">

      <tr>
       <td>           
         <div id="thumb">
         </div>
       </td>
       <td>                      
         <img class="pic" id="main" src="img/Picture.gif" alt="">
       </td>   
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But how can I align the four thumbnails under each other now when I don't have the list? (I had css that put the images under each other vertically).

Comment: You should still be able to use CSS - try working with `#thumb` and `#thumb img` rules, these should be useful. If you're having any particular trouble with that, raise a separate question on here so other people can learn from the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

First, `div` cannot be a child of `ul` and second you shouldn't really use tables for layout (unless making an email template).

If you are just trying to change the src of the main image on the click of the thumbnails, you can use the following js:

```
var images = new Array('img/Plane1.jpg', 'img/Plane2.jpg', 'img/Plane3.jpg', 'img/Plane4.jpg'),
    thumbnails = document.getElementById('thumb').getElementsByTagName('img'),
    mainImage = document.getElementById('main');

for (i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    setClickFunction(i);
}

function setClickFunction(currentIndex) {
    thumbnails[currentIndex].onclick = function() {
        mainImage.src = images[currentIndex];
    };
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jmwrrc14/5/)

[Using links for your large images instead of an array](http://jsfiddle.net/jmwrrc14/6/)